# Spotify iOS SDK Refresh Tokens

Tags: ios, spotify

Evening all!

Quick question for all of those who are familiar with the Spotify iOS SDK .

(Please note: For those who don't, please don't provide any assistance because it is a procedural question rather than a programatic question).

So, I have successfully authenticated and received a session token (and accompanying Refresh_Token on the server). My understanding is that the Refresh_Token is not passed back to the iOS app and should be stored on the server to be used when the original session has expired and you need to renew without user interaction.

My question is how are people storing the Refresh_Token? Surely you would need to store it alongside the user's Spotify username (which is never disclosed to the tokenswap server?!). How would I go about getting the username?

I've played around to see what gets passed to the Token Swap server, when you first request a session, it passes `Code` and returns `Session`, `Bearer`, `Expires` and `Refresh Token`. When you ask for a renew, it passes the Spotify username only. So I don't have anything which is kept the same across both requests to use as a unique identifier of which user is making the request.

Hopefully, that can be understood! Please don't hesitate to ask for clarification!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spotify iOS SDK ships with a token swap server that stores refresh tokens by username for you. Open it up and you'll have en example on how to do exactly what you want to do:

https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/blob/master/Demo%20Projects/spotify_token_swap.rb

Basically, have your token swap server do a request to the `/me` endpoint to get the username.

Comment: Is this service still needed? I have found an old issue on Github (https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/159) which is unfortunately closed and not updated sinse Feb'15...

Comment: page not found please help